(potentially Horror anthology) episode where spoiler at the end is family is dead all along approx early 2000's
Watched this in early 2000's but it might have been from late 90's as well.
The main character was the teenage daughter, who had red/brown hair and she's into this dude that works around the house, sort of like a gardener or something. I can't remember if he's dead or not. Anyway her family's warning her not to go out or not to go too far or something like that but she's testing the waters, being a teen and all and she's thirsting for that dude. In the end something happens, an accident I think and she realizes she's dead and her family explains that she's been dead all along and so have they; her little brother was playing with some matches and ended up setting the house on fire (something they had foreshadowed earlier in the episode because I remember them telling him not to play with matches earlier in the show).
This was just one episode out of a tv show, that was probably an anthology of horror. It was probably American but it might have been Canadian too. 

Nevermind, I found it. After extensive googling of horror anthology shows from the 2000's I came upon "Night Visions" and on imdb I saw an image of the teenage girl from that episode so problem solved. The episode is titled "My So-Called Life And Death" and it's the 16th episode of season 1. And after looking at the synopsis I can confirm it is indeed that episode/show I was looking for.
